# importing python dask package on aws MWAA airflow not working

Tags: airflow, dask, mwaa

I am trying to import dask package on AWS MWAA (airflow) using requirements.txt, by adding "dask==2022.6.0" line to the file.
Not only the import does not work, the other packages are not imported anymore.
It is like MWAA does not recognize requirements.txt file anymore.
Anyone encountered this?

Comment: What version of Apache Airflow are you running?

Answer (score 1):

MWAA is constrained to installing `dask==2021.4.0`. Other versions will not install and will break package installation overall. The complete list of package version constraints is here: https://github.com/aws/aws-mwaa-local-runner/blob/main/docker/config/constraints.txt

Comment: changed it to dask==2021.4.0 and it works, thanks!!

Comment: Great! If this is the correct answer to your question, feel free to accept it.